# EF database first role names with foreign keys?

Tags: database, entity-framework

I'm using EF Database First. In the db we have a lot of fk's from one table to another (same). When generating the model, EF uses the other ends table name as the role name. This is a problem. I have made a small example below, to illustrate the problem.

I would like the generated code to use the fk-name, instead of the table name. The model VS is generating now works like this:

```
aTrip.Location
aTrip.Location1
aTrip.Location2
```

when I would like to have

```
aTrip.coming_from
aTrip.arrives_to
aTrip.next_dest
```

Now, I can change the role names in VS. The problem with that is that if I re-import, all my changes are lost. Also, there will be a lot of tedious renaming, since our db contains a lot of fk's like this example.

What I would like to, is to change how VS generates the model, and use the fk's col name, which is much more correct. Can that be done?

```
+----------------+                   +-------------+
|    Trip        |                   |Location     |
+----------------+                   |             |
|                |                   +-------------+
|                |                   |  Name       |
|                |*                 1|             |
|   coming_from  ---------------------             |
|                |                   |             |
|                |                   |             |
|                |*                 1|             |
|   arrives_to   ---------------------             |
|                |                   |             |
|                |                   |             |
|                |*                 1|             |
|    next_dest   ---------------------             |
|                |                   |             |
+----------------+                   +-------------+
```

Comment: Code First, so you have somewhat control over this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I stumbled across it and thought I'd give my opinion.

Now, I don't know how to answer the specific question regarding changing the default naming of foreign keys in an import of a database to a model.  There may be a way, but I don't know it!  If anyone does, then go for it, I'd like to hear it too.

What I would do in this situation, however, is look at how the changes are being made in the database.  This may not fit your setup, but if the database is only to be used from this one application, you could move from database-first to model-first.

After your initial import from the database, and generate the model, I would make the model the original source of the database, and make all changes there, and update the database accordingly.  That would mean you can rename the relationships in whatever way you want, and not have to repeat that task each time the database is changed.

I completely understand that if your situation is more complex than that, this may not be applicable in the slightest, however it might be an option for some.

Of course, you could always go one step further and define the model code-first, which I personally prefer to work with, but that's just my opinion!